# slow findOne performance on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

For some reason, MongoDB is taking an abnormally long time (upwards of 4 seconds) to perform findOne for only one of my databases through nodeJS. In particular, when I run the following line code

```
x = new Date()
markovData = await markovModel.findOne({name: "Markov"})
y = new Date()
console.log(y.getTime() - x.getTime())
```

It takes about 4360ms. For reference, the markov database currently only has one entry.

In comparison, when I  try this on another one of the databases:

```
x = new Date()
profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
y = new Date()
console.log(y.getTime() - x.getTime())
```

It takes about 63ms.

I'm a total novice in MongoDB and Javascript so I'm sure I'm leaving out important information, but I really can't figure this one out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to add index on the fields you most often?

Comment: You need to use the `explain` method on the query to find its database access performance (_not_ this: `console.log(y.getTime() - x.getTime())`).